# How can I rewrite GET variable in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting, permalinks

Is it possible to rewrite :

`http://www.steffiandmihanta.com/2011/fashion/3781-lateef-for-ms-photography?people`

to

`http://www.steffiandmihanta.com/2011/fashion/3781-lateef-for-ms-photography/people`

Please ?

Comment: What does `?people` stand for? What is its function?

Comment: I need this parameter to show/hide something on the page

Answer (score 1):

You can use following rewrite rules to achieve that:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(people)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}/%1? [L,R]
```

Comment: You need to give more info here eg: what doesn't work? what do you see in Apace logs files like access.log error.log? Besides in which .htaccess you placed it? (Wordpress or Root) How is your combined .htaccesss looking now? I don't have wordpress installed on my host but I have tested it without that and it is working fine.

Comment: There were few other questions too :)

Comment: I don't understand the question about "combined". In my logs, I have 404

Comment: Please append your .htaccess in your question above. Also provide relevant part of your error.log to help investigation. When you open this link `http://www.steffiandmihanta.com/2011/fashion/3781-lateef-for-ms-photography/people` in browser do you get page fine?